# Batch render different than single frame render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a cycles scene with 2 different render layers on it that are setup so that I have an object and its shadow rendering onto a transparent background.

When i render a single frame by just hitting f12 this is what i get (and that is what I want): [image: Correct image]

Then when i hit the batch render button this is what i get (and its not what i want): [image: incorrect image]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Your batch render doesn't store alpha information in you PNG. As i'm not familiar with batch render, so sompeone else sould answer how to get alpha channel in .PNG using batch render. Do you mean "render animation"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. Think that we know nothing about your scene and how you set it up or what kind of render settings  you are using.